# Report about the use of mentions in Teams Channel

Tags: powerbi, office365, microsoft-teams

I am requested to provide the following information from a Teams Channels:

1. Who used a specific mention/tag example @support and how many times(total tags by each individual)
2. Who responded to the tag above, and how many times.

The Reporting and Analytics tool in 0365 doesn't provide this information
I have tried Microsoft Graph API
I have tried Power BI(though I do not have adequate knowledge of this to claim it doesn't do the job)
I see it is possible to get this data using TyGraph for Teams, but I have to go through a long process to acquire this product, just to be used by one team.

Anybody has any idea how I could go about this request?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to use Microsoft Graph to gather the info and Power BI/Excel to manipulate and present the data.